# What is the most appropriate way on ASE to advance an argument that a topic not be closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

What is the most appropriate way on ASE to advance an argument that a topic not be closed as a duplicate, and invite votes to re-open?

Specifically, *where* should such an argument be posted?  As comments to the question?  In the ASE chat forum?  As a question in the meta site?  Somewhere else?

I'm still a bit new to all the ins and outs of how this site really works.

Answer (score 3):

> If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site. Asking in the meta site allows those who took the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues being discussed.

Help Center > Asking > [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

FWIW, a question closed as dupe, needs to be differentiated well-enough in the question body from the dupe by the asker. Note: It does not matter if the newer question gathered new answers that weren't covered in the older topic.

Comment: @quietflyer: If you think you have a valid case, i.e. according to the closure/reopening rules, ask here on meta. If not, instead ask about the closure/reopening rules (you can specify a topic if it helps). Also I recommend checking the help center and the main meta, plenty of information there regarding the rules.

Comment: @quietflyer: Here's the general FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931 HTH.

Comment: @quietflyer: I think what I quoted from the help center is clearer than my comment, "the best place to ask is on the community's meta site." Meaning: You would **post a question, here on meta, asking why it was closed, and why you think it should not have been closed.** (btw, if we're talking about the glider/gravity question, according to the FAQ I linked, the edits should come from the author, and regarding the comment you left, a question marked as duplicate is not deleted nor will it be deleted, so no effort is wasted, it will still be found and linked.)

Comment: @quietflyer: No that's not right, a test you can do: bookmark it, log off, and visit it, or even search for it. It remains accessible to the public, and since there are answers, it will **not** be deleted. This is also explained in the help center and FAQ.

Comment: @quietflyer: that's for the "banner", not the post, and I don't blame you. The new wording is not good.