# Would it be appropriate to set up a ASE chat room specifically to discuss whether an answer is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

Would it be appropriate to set up a ASE chat room specifically to discuss whether a question is a duplicate?

Also, in a case where there is some legitimate case for the argument, would this likely be a more effective or less effective strategy than simply posting to the main chat room (hangar)?

Also, in such a case, is there some other strategy I have not mentioned above, that would likely be more effective, or more appropriate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most appropriate way on ASE to advance an argument that a topic not be closed as a duplicate?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-on-ase-to-advance-an-argument-that-a-topic-not)

Answer (score 2):

You already asked [What is the most appropriate way on ASE to advance an argument that a topic not be closed as a duplicate?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4057/14897)

"most appropriate" should cover it, why go for a lesser option?

Nonetheless, for that to work, the users that you wish to discuss the topic with them (the voters and all those with the reopening privilege), may not be chat users, or may decline the format, since here, meta, is more appropriate.

> whether an answer is a duplicate

Closing a question is not about the **answer** being a duplicate, it's about the **question.**

Comment: "Closing a question is not about the answer being a duplicate, it's about the question."-- I knew that.  Meant to say "question" not "answer".  Would edit, but would invalidate your answer.